# laravel: getting problems on login to dashboard because it redirects me to login page even i pass correct access credentials

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

i just deployed my website developed on laravel and it all works on localhost but after deploying i have problem to login to dashboard.First i have problem of session expired but after removing \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,from kernel.php that problem was solved but now it only redirects me to login page.

i checked every code but did not found any code mistake.

//AdminController.php

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
public function adminlogin(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->input();
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'], 
'password'=>$data['password'], 'admin'=>'1'])){
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin.login')- 
 >with('flash_message_error', 'Invalid Access Credentials');
        }
    }
    return view ('backend.admin_login');
 }


 public function dashboard(){
    return view ('backend.adminlayouts.admin_dashboard');
 }
 }
```

//routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/login', 'AdminController@adminlogin')- 
>name('admin.login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')- 
>name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

//redirectIfAuthenticate

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
 {
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }else {

        return redirect()->action('AdminController@adminlogin')- 
 >with('flash_message_error', 'Please Login To Access');
    }

    return $next($request);
 }
```

//authenticate.php

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

//kernel.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
     ],
```

//admin_login.blade.php

```
<form class="form-signin"  action="{{route('admin.login')}}" method="post">
          @csrf
```

Please help to fix out this bug, i want to login to my dashboard.

Comment: Hello. Try clearing caches. `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan route:clear`. Also, make sure your .env is correctly set up and clear the config cache `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you're entering the `admin.login` route? I've noticed you're using the `Auth::routes()` first, which will match the initial GET request route on `/login`. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1150

Try to uncomment the default `Auth::routes` and pass the necessary routes like logout, register, password/reset, etc. in manually.